# Admob app becomes inactive with no reason

Tags: android, admob

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [After publishing new version of android app to google play admob status changed to inactive and no ads are displayed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11703415/after-publishing-new-version-of-android-app-to-google-play-admob-status-changed)

After several months working perfectly, one of my apps turned inactive without having made ​​any recent changes and receiving thousands of daily requests. I tried to contact and ask admob but I didn't received useful answers.

Anyone had the same problem ?

Comment: I had the same issue when the admob moderation disabled my app. Maybe they did the same to you?

Comment: Looks like several questions have been asked at the same time on this subject (See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11703415/after-publishing-new-version-of-android-app-to-google-play-admob-status-changed) so I guess that Admob could have a problem!?

Comment: Same here, no idea what is happening.