# After publishing new version of android app to google play admob status changed to inactive and no ads are displayed

Tags: android, admob

Admob was showing ads on my application, everything was working fine. Then I created a new version of that app, uploaded it to google play and ads stopped appearing. In admob the status of this app chnaged to "Inactive: AdMob has never received an ad request for your site" (the bubble got from green to red) despite the fact that there is some revenue from the first version, when the ads were still working.

I didn't change adUnitId, it's the same like Publisher id shown in admob. When I run that app from eclipse test ads appear correctly, but only test ads. If I remove my device from list of test devices an ad is never displayed.

In LogCat I get these messages: Received ad url: "url" and then onFailedToReceiveAd(Ad request successful, but no ad returned due to lack of ad inventory.) Ok, it is possible that I don't get ads because of my locality or something, but how can that be with all few hundred people that used my app? The problem must be somewhere else.

What could be the problem? Do I need to create a new app in admob for every app update in google play store? (which seems unlogical to me)

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had this issue once, and the admob moderation team had blocked my app. Maybe yours is blocked too.

Comment: I removed that app, added the same app to admob (every setting, description the same). Then, of course, publisher id was different, but everything started working. Strange.

Comment: I did the same thing when my app was first blocked by admob. They blocked it a second time. I didn't know what was going on by that time, and I sent them an email. They replied 1 month later, saying that my app had been removed for a secret reason (they wouldn't tell me why), and that my account may be suspended if I uploaded it again.

Comment: @Joel Did you then get the money from that app for the ads. I am having the same problem and losing a lot of revenue as my app is in trending catergory.

Comment: I got all the money earned before the app was blocked by admob. But as soon as your app is blocked, you get no impressions and no money. Do not create a new admob id for the same app or your account will be banned. Just use another ad provider and update your app.

Comment: Mine blocked too. Very sad.

Comment: No impressions here too, I did not receive any warnings, happened after I've uploded a new version to Apple's App Store; both new and old versions are affected.